# How to get my modal to trigger. Passing value with respond_to :js

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to trigger my modal from a .js.erb file.
Here is my controller

**teams_controller.rb**

```
def edit
    @user = current_user
    @team = @user.teams.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
     end
end
```

Here is my view from which I'm calling the modal and passing the value of team.

**users/show.html.erb**

```
    <% @teams.all.each do |team| %>
        <%= link_to 'edit', edit_team_path(team),  {:remote => true, 'data-toggle' =>  "modal", 'data-target' => '#modal-window'}  %>
    <% end %>
```

Here is my teams/edit.js.erb

```
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-md modal-8" id="modal-window" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mysmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <%= form_for @team do |f| %>
            <% end %>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I'm recieving this error from the console when I click edit in users/show.html.erb

```
VM27914:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:246)
at rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:173
at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:230)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written `HTML` in a `.js` file. You need to wrap all your HTML tags in double quotes and then the attributes in single quotes.

You need to return a single string using Javascript which includes all the stuff you've got in the edit.js.erb

Comment: That's a simplified explanation. But my point is that you've got to correct the issue of having html in a `.js` file is what I'm getting at.

Comment: I understand what you mean and I will give it a try thank you.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Would you mind marking my answer as correct please? I have a dream of one day having 1,000 points on Stack Overflow, lol =)